# Language used in bison/yacc files

Tags: c++, llvm, flex-lexer, yacc, ml-yacc

I wonder what is the language used in the curly braces of the rule section in yacc/bison files like the following and if there is any good reference about it.

```
stmts : stmt { $$ = new NBlock(); $$->statements.push_back($<stmt>1); }
  | stmts stmt { $1->statements.push_back($<stmt>2); }
  ;
```

and in the above code, for example, why it is written `$<stmt>$2` not just `$2`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually C code with a custom macro preprocessor.

yacc/bison replaces all occurence of $$ with C code that refers to the semantic value of the rule's target component, and $n with the semantic value of rule element #n.

The code is actually C (and by extension, C++), and $$ and $n get replaced by bison itself, with C code that refers to the rule target's, or rule element's semantic value.

[See this chapter of bison's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Semantics.html#Semantics) for more information.

Comment: I will read the reference. Could you please answer the second part ? I did not see any difference between { $1->statements.push_back($<stmt>2); } and { $1->statements.push_back($2); } . In many codes I have seen , they use them differently.

Comment: This is fully explained in Bison's documentation, in the link that I provided. Copy-pasting contents of other web sites into stackoverflow.com does not accomplish anything useful.

Comment: I'm not sure that "custom macro-processor" is the best possible description of the process. Bison uses `m4` as a macro processor (or perhaps it would be better to say templating language). `m4` is a more-or-less standard macro language. The substitution of `$` and `@` tokens into the appropriate macros is done during the lexical scan of the code, see the function `handle_action_dollar` in `scan-code.l`. I suppose you could call that a macro-substitution, but it seems to me more like a transpilacion, fwiw. Anyway, upvoted.